# applying rmultinom in R without iterating over matrix

Tags: r

I want to use rmultinom(), combined with a transition matrix, to generate whole number outputs that, when summed, are equal to the original values. However, I can't figure out how to do it without iterating over the matrix. Here is an example:

```
a = matrix(runif(16),nrow=4,ncol=4)
a = apply(a,2,FUN = function(x) x/sum(x))

b = c(5,7,5,9)
out = c(0,0,0,0) # initialize
for (i in 1:ncol(a)){
  tmp = rmultinom(1,b[i],a[,i])
  out = tmp + out
}
sum(out) == sum(b) ## Should eval to true
```

`a` represents a transition matrix, with each column summing to 1. `b` is a starting vector of integers. The loop iterates along the columns to generate a vector in `out` that sums to the initial numbers in `b`.  How can I do this without using a loop? The results would be similar to if I multiply `a %*% b`, but this leaves me with floating point values.

Comment: The rows should sum to 1, not the columns. P_ij, going from i -> j, should sum to 1 over all j.

Comment: For my purposes, the columns sum to 1 (demographic modeling of growth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `apply` and `rowSums` (this will be stochastic):

```
library(magrittr)
set.seed(1)
a = matrix(runif(16),nrow=4,ncol=4)
a = apply(a,2,FUN = function(x) x/sum(x))
b <- c(5,7,5,9) 

out <- purrr::map(1:4, ~rmultinom(1, b[.x], a[,.x])) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  matrix(nrow = 4) %>%
  rowSums()

out
[1] 7 7 9 3
sum(out)
[1] 26
sum(b)
[1] 26
```

Comment: My example was too simple. If you have non-equal starting values (e.g. c(5,4,3,4)), it doesn't work. My example doesn't work either, but I am going to modify the question.

Comment: @user44796 I'll updated my awnser.

Comment: That's purrrfect! I hadn't seen the use of purrr::map before